# Import remote XML using import and export wizard (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql-server, xml, import

What I need to do:

Import data from remote XML files (>20 different schemas, available by uri) to SQL Server 2008. The data should be imported once per day.

I decide to use  "Import And Export Data" tools from the SQL Server 2008 Package.

This tools works fine for importing data from Excel, but I don't know how to config XML File as a data source.

The problem is that I can't find somthing like "XML Provider" in data source list.

1. Should I install some special "XML Data Provide" on server machine?
2. Maybe do someone know some better (FAST-programming) solution (hard coding in .net/LINQu it's not a good idea).

Thanks for help!

Comment: What do these XML files look like? If they're not too huge and overly complex, you could probably load them using just the XQuery support in T-SQL ....

Comment: 5-15 MB, the structure are quite simple but each of them has different structure so whats why I look for some "wizzard solution"